# Starting out with Dagger 2 - class not injecting

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, dagger

I am trying to inject a `singleton` repository into a `Foo` class to use it.
the `repo` is not injected and still null, why am i missing some annotation or that's not the proper way

**Repository.java**

```
@Singlton
public class Repository {...}
```

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {
  @Inject Repository repo;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dagger works via *Components*: Specifically, you pass Dagger the list of things you want or that you want to do (Component interfaces) as well as how you want to provide non-trivial dependencies (Modules), and then Dagger generates an implementation of your interface that does what you want.

You've shown us Foo and its dependency Repository, but if you haven't shown us the Component, I'm guessing that you might not have one. At this point you can choose how to proceed: you can either get your Foo from a Dagger Component, or you can create your Foo as you usually do and then call `inject(foo)` to inject a particular Foo instance with all of its `@Inject` fields (including your Repository). The former is usually preferred to make a straightforward interface, but the latter works well with objects where you don't control the lifecycle (like Android's Application, Activity, Fragment, Service, and other similar objects).

### Getting Foo

If you choose to let Dagger create your Foo, you'll need to **create an `@Inject`-annotated constructor** (even an empty one) for both Foo and Repository, then **write a Component** like this:

```
@Component public interface YourComponent {
  Foo createFoo();  // Name this whatever you like; it's a factory because
                    // of its return type and lack of parameters.
}
```

Excellent! Now as long as you have an implementation of YourComponent, you could create a Foo and inject it. You haven't written an implementation, but if you did, it might look like this:

```
public YourComponentImpl implements YourComponent {
  @Override public Foo createFoo() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.repo = new Repository();
    return foo;
  }
}
```

However, you don't have to write one: Dagger will write one that is *equivalent to the one above* for you as soon as you [compile the YourComponent interface with the Dagger compiler](https://github.com/google/dagger#installation), which means compiling it with `javac` with the Dagger compiler specified as a source code processor. Dagger works as an annotation processor that reads the `@Component` interface and generates a class called DaggerYourComponent. After that, you can get an instance by calling the static method `DaggerYourComponent.create()`, and then on that instance call `yourComponent.createFoo()` wherever you'd otherwise call `new Foo()`.

### Injecting an existing Foo

To inject, you follow a similar pattern as above, except your method should take one argument (your existing Foo instance), and consequently you don't need to add an `@Inject`-annotated constructor onto Foo because Dagger doesn't ever construct one. You do for Repository, though, because Dagger will create that.

```
@Component public interface YourComponent {
  void inject(Foo foo);  // Name this whatever you like; it's a members injector
                         // because it takes exactly one argument.
}
```

This will allow you to call `DaggerYourComponent.create()` like above to create your component, and then call `yourComponent.inject(foo)` to inject a Repository into the `repo` field you annotated.

Once you get more familiar with Dagger, you can start to build off of what you know and add Modules, inject with `Provider<>` injections, or add scopes so you can *reuse instances* rather than creating new ones each time. Check the [User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html) for more.

Comment: thanks alot that was a simple straight forward explanation that took me 2 days of searching and experimenting, but i have a question about the classes you don't own like Activities, Services etc...
you need the second approach of passing your class instance to your generated dagger component `inject()` method in order to fill in the member fields dependencies.
if you want to test an Activity you are calling `inject(this)` of my production component in`onCreate()`, if i need to switch to another `MockComponent`, is there an easy approach to that without changing the Activity code every time..

Comment: i meant i can call `inject()` out of the Activity to make it independent from choosing a specific component, but you can't do that in production you have to inject from the inside of Activity, and using `dagger-android` gave me a head ache i like to make my own solutions after understanding the basics.

Comment: For a simple `dagger.android` equivalent, your Activity should call `getApplication()`, then you expose your component through a method like `getComponent()`, and then you call `inject(this)` making sure that your Component has specific methods for your FooActivity, BarActivity, and so forth. (A plain Activity won't work because Dagger writes a different implementation for each of your classes.) If you can't write an Application subclass that fits your needs for testing, consider extracting the `getApplication().getComponent()` call and cast to a _method_ and then _subclassing it in tests_.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your injector and declare your singletons? For example, by creating a class annotated with `@Module` to signal to `Dagger` to search within available methods for possible instance providers. try follow [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) example.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes i tried that didn't work either, i tested also a very simple Injection just a class `Bar` field annotated with `@Inject` in my `MainActivity` and that also kept not injected and still null
am i missing some `Dagger` initialization or whats the problem.